# Numpy.ndarray: iteration by specific axes of an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multidimensional array. And I have to iterate via *some* of its axes. If I needed all axes, I could use `nditer`, but if I need only the specific ones, I have to do it manually:

```
my_array = np.arange(3 * 4 * 5).reshape((3, 4, 5))
for i in range(my_array.shape[0]):
    for j in range(my_array.shape[1]):
        print(i, j)
        # Here should be some processing of the 3rd dimension items of the (i,j)
```

Cannot you advice me a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider passing to a single loop, and using `ndindex` ([docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html#numpy.ndindex)):

```
my_array = np.arange(3 * 4 * 5).reshape((3, 4, 5))
for ij in np.ndindex(my_array.shape[:2]):
    i,j=ij
    print(i,j)
```

Comment: Thank you, comrade! It's just what I need.
^__^

Comment: `np.ndindex` uses `nditer`.  `np.ndindex((2,3))._it` is an `nditer` instance.  Check the code in `index_tricks.py` for more details.

Comment: yes, that's where the source of `ndindex` is [(link)](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py#L510), and I am not surprised that it uses `as_strided`. Am I missing your point?